# Install Knowledgebase plugin on Bitnami Redmine 3.1.1

Tags: ruby, rake, redmine, bitnami, redmine-plugins

I'm trying to install [Knowledgebase plugin](https://github.com/alexbevi/redmine_knowledgebase) on Bitnami Redmine 3.1.1 (running on Windows Server 2012R2). I tried as follows but no luck.

1. Downloaded [redmine-3.0-compat](https://github.com/alexbevi/redmine_knowledgebase/tree/redmine-3.0-compat)
   and copied it to htdocs\plugins and renamed the extracted folder as "redmine_knowledgebase".
2. Downloaded acts-as-taggable-on and redmine_acts_as_taggable_on from Github and put them in htdocs\lib\plugins
3. Opened "Bitnami Redmine Stack Environment" window and execute "bundle install --no-deployment"
4. Executed "rake redmine:plugins RAILS_ENV=production"

Then I got the following error and the plugin does not work.

> rake aborted!
>   
> LoadError: cannot load such file -- generators/acts_as_taggable_on/migration/
>   plates/active_record/migration
>   
> C:/Bitnami/redmine-3.1.1-0/apps/redmine/htdocs/lib/plugins/redmine_acts_as_ta
>   ble_on/lib/redmine_acts_as_taggable_on/migration.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
>   C:/Bitnami/redmine-3.1.1-0/apps/redmine/htdocs/lib/plugins/redmine_acts_as_ta
>   ble_on/lib/redmine_acts_as_taggable_on/initialize.rb:3:in`'
>   C:/Bitnami/redmine-3.1.1-0/apps/redmine/htdocs/plugins/redmine_knowledgebase/
>   t.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
>   C:/Bitnami/redmine-3.1.1-0/apps/redmine/htdocs/lib/redmine/plugin.rb:155:in`
>   ck in load'
>   C:/Bitnami/redmine-3.1.1-0/apps/redmine/htdocs/lib/redmine/plugin.rb:146:in 
>   `h'
>   C:/Bitnami/redmine-3.1.1-0/apps/redmine/htdocs/lib/redmine/plugin.rb:146:in`
>   d'
>   C:/Bitnami/redmine-3.1.1-0/apps/redmine/htdocs/config/initializers/30-redmine
>   :21:in `<top (required)>'
>   C:/Bitnami/redmine-3.1.1-0/apps/redmine/htdocs/config/environment.rb:14:in`<
>    (required)>'
>   C:/Bitnami/redmine-3.1.1-0/apps/redmine/htdocs/lib/tasks/redmine.rake:52:in `
>   ck (2 levels) in '
>   Tasks: TOP => redmine:plugins:migrate => environment
>   (See full trace by running task with --trace)

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bitnami developer here.

It seems that the plugin is not compatible with your Redmine version. It is only compatible with Redmine 2.5.x, 2.4.x, 2.3.x, 2.2.x.
You can check it here:
https://www.redmine.org/plugins/redmine_knowledgebase

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So there's no way to install this plugin on Redmine 3.1.1 at the moment?

Comment: Probably the developer (alexbevi) could help you to determine the requirements in a better way.

Answer (score 1):

A quick workaround is to just delete `db/migrate/20130513154700_add_tags_and_taggings.rb` from the knowledgebase, then run the migrations.